# Asus Eee PC 1201n support package (jupiter)

Tags: asus, support, jupiter, unsupported-packages

Few years ago Asus provided a Linux package which internally used name "jupiter". Now it's not available. Searching for "jupiter" with apt-cache doesn't yield any results. Is there a way to have this package on Ubuntu? From where to download it, maybe there is an Ubuntu repository for this?

Comment: Is this the OEM install Linux version for eee with the awful full-screen windows, or some sort of utility? I have had eee's for years, but don't recognise the name 'Jupiter'? What sort of beast are we looking for here? If it's [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/06/jupiter-take-advantage-of-asus-super.html) then it's dead.

Comment: @MarkWilliams: It was a set of utilities, AFAIR I downloaded it from Asus support page. It used name "jupiter" for directories, but wasn't named that in general, I think. It provided: hardware wifi enable/disable, hardware bluetooth enable/disable, and it also allowed to do something with CPU, cannot tell as I didn't use it for this. All I need is ability to do hardware wifi reset.

Comment: Not, I presume, just the Fn-F2 reset? I think you can do that in BIOS IIRC - don't have mine with me today, so can't check it for you! The Fn-F2 is meant to be a HW on/off, as opposed to the network-manager 'disable' command. [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2245288) thread has a very long list of ways to mess with wifi - and the bottom line was, BIOS...

Answer (score 0):

Just to fill in an answer, no, Jupiter is discontinued, but there are many utilities & documented means of doing what it used to do (here & elsewhere) - see comments for specifics!